# Route to child component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, router

I'm trying to navigate from a parent component to its child. My routing module looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GroupComponent } from './group/group.component';
import { GroupDetailComponent } from './group-detail/group-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FocalComponent,
    canActivate: [ProjectTeamGuard || BhrGuard || ManagerGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'my-group',
    component: GroupComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'group-detail',
        component: GroupDetailComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My parent component is executing the following function

```
  public goToGroupDetail() {
    this.router.navigate(["./group-detail"], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
  }
```

And I'm getting the next error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet
>   to load 'GroupDetailComponent' Error: Cannot find primary outlet to
>   load 'GroupDetailComponent

I'm not sure if it has to do with my `routing.module` of the function `goToGroupDetail()` itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have multiple router outlets? One for the parent and one for the children?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are passing a parameter on the path when actually the router doesn't expect one. Does just   this.router.navigate(["./group-detail"]) fail as well?

Comment: The error indicates that you don't have a `router-outlet` inside your `GroupComponent`'s template. And btw `canActivate: [ProjectTeamGuard || BhrGuard || ManagerGuard]` doesn't make any sense at all.